# comma separated list in php

Tags: php, mysql, drupal

I am trying to build a list separated by commas which should look like this (green, orange, red).

```
$i=0;
$taxonomy = $form_state[values][taxonomy][5];
foreach ($taxonomy as $key => $value){
  $result = db_query("SQL CODE goes here");
  if (mysql_num_rows($result)){     
  while ($i<mysql_num_rows($result)){
    $resultset = db_fetch_array($result);
    $comma_separated = implode(",", $resultset);
    $i++;      
  }
  form_set_error("Date", t("$comma_separated. cannot be booked more than once "));
}
```

Comment: In future please take the time to format your code correctly and at check that your question actually makes sense. If you can't be bothered to spend time asking a question, why would you expect people to bother answering it?

Comment: code is missing a closing } on the foreach loop

Comment: Completely unrelated, but `t( some string that depends on variables )` is exceedingly hard to translate later on.

Comment: Are you going to do the same query several times in a foreach loop?

Comment: so many issues with that code.  regardless.. you dont want implode.. you want a $commasep .= $row['whatever'].',';

Comment: Doesn't Drupal return taxonomy per node natively? Why the code?

Comment: As others said, there's no actual question here.

Comment: My apologies if the the question and embedded code was not clear. However it has been resolved with the solution provided by spudley. Basically the question was to create a comma separated list of records retrieved from that database. 

@ Kevin, i am quite new to drupal so i am not sure what you mean..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$resultset=array();
while ($data = db_fetch_array($result)) {
    $resultset[] = $data;
}
$comma_separated = implode(",", $resultset);
```

Answer (score 2):

Someone posted it and I was going to upvote, but they removed it.  I think mysql GROUP_CONCAT would be a good solution, since it looks like getting a comma separated list is the only purpose of this query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$i=0; 
$taxonomy = $form_state[values][taxonomy][5]; 
$result='';
foreach ($taxonomy as $key => $value)
{ 
    $result = db_query("SQL CODE goes here"); 
    if (mysql_num_rows($result)){
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_row()){
           result.=$row[0].',';
        } 
    }
}
result=substr($result,0,-1);
echo $result;
```

Comment: suggest sticking with `db_fetch_array()` rather than `mysql_fetch_row()` - the one is just a wrapper for the other, but it's part of Drupal's database abstraction, so its best to stick with it.

Comment: Go with the solution from Spudley, much cleaner, simpler, and less overhead

Comment: Thank you so much Spudley, your solution worked with a little modification. $resultset[] = $data["name"];