# Making this PHP code more efficient?

Tags: php, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [comma separated list in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4682913/comma-separated-list-in-php)

Problem:

I want to be able to iterate through a list of unknown size, and spit out a comma delimited list.

**For example:**

```
Input:
  $data = array();
  $data[0]['productId'] = 11;
  $data[1]['productId'] = 22;
  $data[2]['productId'] = 33;
  $data[3]['productId'] = 44;
```

**The following code does the trick:**

```
$prodsToCheck = "";
foreach ($data as $d) {
  $prodsToCheck .= $d['productId'].", ";
}
$prodsToCheck = substr($prodsToCheck, 0, strlen($prodsToCheck) - 2); // THIS IS THE IMPORTANT PART

print $prodsToCheck; die();
```

**Result must be**

11, 22, 33, 44

and NOT:

11, 22, 33, 44,

This can't be the quickest way to do this... what is?

Comment: I think it's worth to mention: Your input array doesn't have a key `productId`.

Comment: I sometimes wondered about functionalities like this, too. Your way, while not the most elegant, may still be the fastest. Please consider, that for every other solution there are some (small) checks to do for every element of the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example and your code are incoherent, so I decided to ignore the example since the problem would be too simple otherwise.

You may use implode, array_map and an anonymous function like this:

```
$prodsToCheck = implode(
   ", ", 
   array_map(
       function($element) { return $element['productId'];}, 
       $data));
```

Completely untested and supposed to work with php 5.3+

Comment: Too much code. I'm trying to find one line to solve this with...

Comment: @RD. I really want to downvote this comment only for this "too much code" :D You definitely can't get any more compressed solution like this. And besides: You can even write it on a single line ;)

Comment: okay.... i really thought there was a way to use implode or explode or some other array function to get this done quickly. But it seems this might very well be the fastest way. Going to impliment it now...

Answer (score 1):

`print implode(", ", $array);`

Read up on [implode](http://php.net/implode).

Comment: Looks like the OP only wants the values for the productID key, but the input array makes this confusing

Comment: @WouterH indeed; OP: Please refer to greg0ire's answer if that's what you are looking for. It's really hard to tell.

Comment: -1: SO is really good at upvoting the one answer which is completely wrong. This way would work only for one-dimensional array.

Comment: @tereško: read the question, it was misleading.

Comment: @tereško The OP should be able to solve it's problem with this answer, because it refers directly his problem, even if it's not a copy&paste solution. Additional the questions code snippets are ambiguous.

Comment: Sorry guys... the code should be better now. The issue is not including the last "," and that the array is multidimensional.